# Call NextVC all method on button click without push viewcontroller

Tags: swift

Currently I am making application in which FirstVC has `Print` button it will use for printing data from printer.
All Printing functionality code i have in SecondVC when i click on `Print` button from `firstVC` without going to `SecondVC` i want to call all `SecondVC` method like `viewdidload(),viewwillappear()` and so on.

is it possible?

Comment: Why can't you move the printing code into the first VC? The print button is in the first VC, so naturally the printing functionality code should be in the first VC as well, no?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for viewDidLoad(). But for viewWillAppear() method or other i think it cannot load because the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy.

If you want to call viewDidLoad() without present SecondVC. First you need to instantiate SecondVC and then call method loadViewIfNeeded().

```
let SecondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondViewController
      SecondVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

But you can call all methods in SecondVC manually.